# Cross Hair/ Track Ball Functionality in MS Charts Controls / Dotnetcharting controls

Tags: asp.net

Is the Cross Hair/ Track Ball functionality is available in Ms Charts / dotnetcharting Controls

If yes then Please guide me related to this by providing a link.

Actually i am looking for a chart with following feature -

http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=DELL

Hoping for positive reply

Kind Regards,
D.Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Afer a long time  I think Ms dotnet charts doesnot supports track ball and cross hair functionality

its for silverlight based charting controls